# To iterate and update based on presence of ordinal number in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am having a dataframe containing Address column. My dataframe looks like below. I need to first check if there is an ordinal number in the dataframe and if it is there I need to convert it into words. For example:-

The 3 index has address as  apartment 19th court gorey which should be converted to apartment nineteenth court gorey.

I have written the code for finding ordinal number and converting to word. But I am not able to save the updated record in the original dataframe. The changes should be done only on the particular record with ordinal number and remaining dataframe should be as it is.

The code gives the output as:-
apartment nineteenth court gorey
7 sraid na mara first sea rd strandhill rd

```py
My original dataframe- newdf
    Address
0   2 fairgreen lane bolton callan
1   2 leix rd cabra dublin 7
2   2 woodale view ballycullen firhouse dublin 24
3   apartment 19th court gorey


import re
from num2words import num2words   
for index, row in newdf.iterrows():
    numbers = re.findall('(\d+)(?:st |nd |rd |th )', row['Address'])
    for n in numbers:
        ordinalAsString = num2words(n, ordinal=True)
        newText=re.sub(r"(\d+)(?:st|nd|rd|th)", ordinalAsString, row['Address'])
        print(newText)



My expected result is:-
    Address
0   2 fairgreen lane bolton callan
1   2 leix rd cabra dublin 7
2   2 woodale view ballycullen firhouse dublin 24
3   apartment nineteenth court gorey
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you can use [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with a custom function,

```
from num2words import num2words
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(['2 fairgreen lane bolton callan',
                   '2 leix rd cabra dublin 7',
                   '2nd woodale view ballycullen 15th',
                   'apartment 19th court 20th gorey'], columns=['Address'])

def str_replace(x):
    number = x.group(1)
    extract_num = re.findall(r'\d+', number)[0]
    return num2words(extract_num, ordinal=True)

df['Address'] = df.Address.str.replace(r'(\d+(st|nd|rd|th))', str_replace)

# print(df.Address)

0                2 fairgreen lane bolton callan
1                      2 leix rd cabra dublin 7
2     second woodale view ballycullen fifteenth
3    apartment nineteenth court twentieth gorey
Name: Address, dtype: object
```